# How to separate items in a date column by a space, and only output the first two date components ("YYYY MM")?

Tags: r, date-formatting

I have a data frame (eg):

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a","b","c"),
                 date = c("2019-01-15","2019-02-08","2019-03-10")
)
```

I want to create a new column (new_date) that re-formats the date column so it would look like:

```
name    date    new_date
a    2019-01-15 2019 01
b    2019-02-08 2019 02
c    2019-03-10 2019 03
```

I've been trying to use a strsplit with no luck.

Comment: what about `format(df$date, format="%Y %m")`?

Comment: `gsub()` or else `format()` as @RAB showed. `strsplit` is not what the output you want is a string, not a list. If you got a list you'd only have to paste it back into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new_date = format(as.Date(date), "%Y %m"))

  name       date new_date
1    a 2019-01-15  2019 01
2    b 2019-02-08  2019 02
3    c 2019-03-10  2019 03
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a date format, lubridate has some nice functions to extract the relevant info

```
library(lubridate)
df$new_date <- paste(year(df$date),month(df$date), sep = " ")

> df

  name       date new_date
1    a 2019-01-15   2019 1
2    b 2019-02-08   2019 2
3    c 2019-03-10   2019 3
```

Answer (score 0):

From base R

```
df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date)
df$new_date = format(df$date,'%Y %m')
df
  name       date new_date
1    a 2019-01-15  2019 01
2    b 2019-02-08  2019 02
3    c 2019-03-10  2019 03
```